# Haxe - How do you implement async await for Flash Targets

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, haxe

I currently have this code:

```
package sage.sys;

import com.dongxiguo.continuation.Async;

#if flash
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
#end

class FileSystem implements Async
{
    public static function fetchText(url:String, callback:String->Void) : Void
    {
        var urlLoader = new URLLoader();
        var onLoaderError = function(e : Event) : Void {
        callback(e.type);
    };

    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(_) : Void {
        callback(Std.string(urlLoader.data));
    });

    urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onLoaderError);
    urlLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onLoaderError);

    try {
        urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));
    }
    catch (e : Dynamic)
    {
        callback(Std.string(e));
    }
}

@async
public static function fetch(url:String):String
{
    var result = @await fetchText(url);
    return result;
}
}
```

When I try to run it, it doesn't wait at the await, and returns from the function. How can I make the @await actually enforce itself and and stop running outside the function till the value is resolved from the async call?

`Lib used: https://github.com/proletariatgames/haxe-continuation`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really. The function, in which you call `fetchText()` will never "wait" in that sense.

However according to the documentation of "haxe-continuation" it will put everything after your `@await FileSystem.fetchText()` expression into a new function, which will be passed as the `callback` parameter of `fetchText()`. So in code it kind of "looks" like it is waiting.

According to the documentation you have to make sure that you put `@async` in front of the function which uses `fetchText()`. According to that something like this should work (untested):

```
@async function someFunction(): Void {
  var result1 = @await FileSystem.fetchText(someUrl);
  var result2 = @await FileSystem.fetchText(anotherUrl);
  trace(result1);
  trace(result2);
}
```

The 2 traces at the end of the function should happen after `result1` and `result2` are fetched, even though `someFunction()` actually returned before the traces already.

It might be helpful to see your code which calls `fetchText()`.

Answer (score 1):

How did you use the `fetch` function?

I suppose you should put a callback to it: 

`FileSystem.fetch(url, function(result) trace(result));`

The `fetch` call itself should return immediately, because it is async and the result will be passed to the callback.

I don't think it is possible to make flash block at the fetch call.

Comment: That is how it was being used. I was hoping to do away with the callback.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have already done that when you call `fetchText` with `@await`